# How to build a ResourceManager in libGDX without making the AssetManager static?

Tags: libgdx

It's been 3 days since I started reading about how to manage assets in libGDX. The first thing I read on documentation is never make AssetManager or any of the textures static but still all the examples I have seen till now has AssetManager as static. 
Can somebody share a project/code of AssetManager where it haven't been used as Singleton? 
Or just tell me how to do it.

Comment: So, your question is how to use an ordinary object in an object oriented language? Perhaps expand a bit, what the actual problem is you are having with that.

Answer (score 1):

I used to create `AssetManager` inside my `Main extends Game` class instance . Then since I'm using [Screens](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) I'm pasing `main` instance to the constructor and I can access assetManager through it

```
    public class MyScreen implements Screen {
        protected Main game;

        public MyScreen (Main game)
        {
            this.game = game;

            game.assetManager.load(...
        }
```

Do not know if it is the best way.

---

If you do not want to pass `Game` instance to screens you can use

```
    Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()
```

to get your current `Game` class object

Comment: This looks like something that might work. Can you share the complete implantation of ScreenManager, AssetManager and Main extended game class? It would be a great help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to simply create an instance of the AssetManager in my first screen (which is a loading screen) and then pass it around in every screen via their constructors.

```
    public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {
    private AssetManager assetManager ; 
    }

    public LoadingScreen(){
    assetManager = new AssetManager ();
    }

    //when going to the next screen, when the assetManager finishes loading:

     ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new NextScreen(assetManager,...));
```

Addendum, and in your NextScreen class:

```
    private AssetManager assetManager;

    public NextScreen (AssetManager assetManager){
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    }
```

Comment: In this case I would have to have a seperate AssetManager for each of my screens which is not a good way to manage assets and screens.

Comment: No, not at all. You always use the same AssetManager you created when starting your game. You just pass it around in your screens.

Comment: How can you share the code? In the code you shared you defined AssetManager as private.

Comment: I've added it in my original answer (see addendum). You simply use constructors to pass the object around. So you really have created only 1 assetManager for your entire program.